# Shapefile and CSV coordinates don't match

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm new to QGIS and still trying to get to grips with some basic aspects. I'm trying to create a map by combining a shapefile outlining London boroughs, and a CSV file with a series of records including Latitude and Longitude references, all of which are in the London region. The problem I'm experiencing is that the shapefile and the points from the data are appearing in totally different places in the resulting map.

I assume the issue is something to do with CRS settings, but I could really use some guidance on what I need to do to match these two layers correctly. I've set the CRS on both layers to EPSG:3857, using Set Layer CRS, but they still don't overlap.

The shapefile came from here:
http://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london

Below is a screenshot of some of the data from the CSV:
[image]

What do I need to do beyond setting the CRS to the same value for both layers?

Comment: I'm sure the shapefile from London Datastore will be in British National Grid. Have you enabled projections on the fly? Add the Shapefile first, enable the on-the-fly projection then plot the points in their native CRS

Comment: EPSG:3857 is the wrong CRS for the CSV. You should use WGS84 EPSG:4326.

Comment: Enabling on the fly projection and setting the CRS to WGS84 EPSG:4326 has worked, so thanks very much. What's the best way to work out the correct CRS in future? Thanks!

Comment: If it looks like degrees of latitude and longitude then its probably EPSG:4326. If its web map tiles (google, openstreetmap) then its EPSG:3857. If its British grid references it might be EPSG:27700. If it doesn't look like those then look for metadata or a .prj file!